# Return CSV file using Socket IO + Node.Js failing

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, csv, export-to-csv

I am new to Node.Js and trying to return a CSV file using SOCKET IO on my Node Layer.
This is my client which is in Angular

```
sockets.request('get.csv',data).then(function(response){

                },function(error){
                    console.log('Something went wrong');
                    console.error(error);
                });
```

This is my Node Layer:-
socket.js

```
    socketService.on('get.csv',controller.dataToCSV);
```

This is my dataToCSV function:-

```
   module.exports.dataToCSV  = function (req,res){

   var csv = 'Hello';
    res.attachment('test.csv');
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/csv; charset=utf-8'
    });
    res.end(csv);
    }
```

I am getting an error at res.attachment

```
     TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I am sure I am going wrong in terms of the return type with socket. Any directions would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean `res.send(csv);`? Not `res.end(csv);`.

Comment: @KyleNeedham its res.end(csv)

Comment: Can you check and see if `req` and `res` are what you think they are.

Comment: @KyleNeedham `req` and `res` both are as expected and when I put my debug the request reaches `dataToCSV` function.